# Print JSON Object by key in JADE

Tags: json, node.js, pug

I have a JSON object like this

```
{
  "54634b4ea624675649e91bcd": "2014-12-04T09:21:02.622Z",
  "542e7c720fa8e288631a8298": "2014-12-04T09:21:08.672Z",
  "542c024f0fa8e288631a8285": "2014-12-19T15:28:27.092Z",
  "542beaaf0fa8e288631a8270": "2014-12-19T15:29:22.546Z",
  "542e82db0fa8e288631a8299": "2014-12-19T15:31:30.282Z",
  "542e83870fa8e288631a829a": "2014-12-19T15:32:22.758Z",
  "542e86e50fa8e288631a829c": "2014-12-19T15:33:07.509Z"
}
```

now i want to print the value of the key `542e7c720fa8e288631a8298` which is `2014-12-04T09:21:08.672Z`

How can i print the value of second key in [JADE](http://jade-lang.com/)

I have the key `542e7c720fa8e288631a8298` stored in another variable. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know much about Jade but you may to iterate over the json obj array:

```
each value, key in obj
  h=key
  p=value
```

Then compare your variable(which has key) with 'key'.

Comment: i am aware of `iterate ` method, is there any key|value fetch ?